# Unable to read cookie in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am unable to get the cookies in Angular.js. The code which I used is

```
angular.module('Routes', ['ngRoute','reviewService']).config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider','$cookies','$cookieStore',
function($routeProvider, $locationProvider,$cookies,$cookieStore) {
var user=$cookies['username']
if(user !='undefined')
    {
    $routeProvider
       .when('/', {
         templateUrl: '/view/home.html',
         controller: 'myController'
    })
............
```

The error which I am getting in browser console is

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Routes due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cookies
........
```

Comment: is `$username` exist in cookies??

Comment: Yes. I is available.

Comment: I think you should use (user !== undefined)

Comment: The error which I am getting in browser console is                            Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Routes due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cookies

Comment: You should be able to just do if (user)

Comment: I am unable to get the user value itself.

Comment: `Unknown provider: $cookies` tells you that you didn't load `ngCookies` module in your app

Comment: Now I have added ngCookies but still I am receiving the same error. I have also added <script src="angular-cookies.js"> this tag in my HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this code is working fine..

```
angular.module('Routes',['ngRoute','reviewService','ngCookies']).config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
 var $cookies;
  angular.injector(['ngCookies']).invoke(function(_$cookies_) {
    $cookies = _$cookies_;
  });    
var user=$cookies['username']
console.log("user name:",user);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('Routes', ['ngRoute','reviewService', 'ngCookies'])
```

$cookies is in ngCookies module, you need to import. Don't forget to add `<script>` tag in html.

Comment: @Jayanth did you add <script src="angular-cookies.js"> in your html?

Comment: My bad. $cookies is a service instead of a provider and you can only use providers in module.config.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to either. Maybe you can use the raw cookie instead of $cookies.